# Web forms: Go back in history without refreshing page

Tags: webforms, navigation

Is it possible to go back in a page without reloading it?

I am developing a Web Forms website and every time a go back in history, the page reloads (and takes a long time).

Following is the curl of the page:

[image: curl --head https://www. .com.br/ /(s(e4hfm...4xa))/ConsultaProdutosItens.aspx]

Comment: Yes, there's an entire wave of new technology surrounding this ideology called Single-Page Applications (SPAs). They typically use the JS [`History`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History_API) API

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Honestly, no.

The life cycle of a Web Form is very specific and the page goes through it every time it is run (that is every time you request it through your browser).

On the other hand, you can always optimize your page to make it load faster. How you do it depends on many things one of which is what code runs on the server side upon loading and if any portions of that code can be either optimized for speed or moved in event handlers to be executed at a later point in time. For example, if you're fetching data from a database when your page loads consider applying paging to narrow the number of selected rows.

Please, feel free to ask a new question if you decide to take that course of action.